# How to write this MySql query using Rails3 syntax?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9

```
SELECT  `subscriptions`.*, DATE_ADD(`subscriptions`.created_at, INTERVAL `packages`.validity DAY) as end_date
     FROM  `subscriptions`  INNER JOIN `packages` ON `packages`.`id` = `subscriptions`.`package_id`
    order by end_date;
```

Comment: Have you attempted this yourself yet? I mean, we could help out... but it'd be better starting from what you've already got!

Comment: Yes this query is working for me Subscription.find_by_sql("this_query"). but I feel sad 'cause I worked hard to make my rails app compatible with other database systems Not only Mysql, and this complex query destroyed my dreams. Specially these DATE_ADD and INTERVAL functions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a model Subscription that is a subclass of ActiveRecord::Base
Then it is simply just

Subsccription.select("`subscriptions`.*, DATE_ADD(`subscriptions`.created_at, INTERVAL `packages`.validity DAY) as end_date).joins(:packages).order(:end_date)

I may have some syntax wrong, such as it may be :package not :packages. But the basic